# Как установить только для последней изменённой записи значение одного столбца?

Tags: oracle, plsql, триггер, oracle12c

Необходимо обеспечить существование в таблице единственной строки с определенным значением. То есть, чтобы при обновлении и добавлении записей занчение колонкаи текущей запии приобретало значение 1, а все оставшиеся - 0.

Попробовал сделать это триггером. С `before insert` все нормально. А вот что для update придумать? Или может есть какие-то еще варианты решения помимо триггеров?

Пример:

```
-- Создаем таблицу
create table tx (
  id integer,
  val varchar2(100)
);

-- Данные
-- truncate table tx

insert into tx
select level, 0 from dual connect by level < 11;

update tx set val = 1 where id = 5;
commit;
```

Добавляться может только 1 запись, обновляться тоже.

При добавлении и изменении надо:

1. Проставлять прежней записи с `val = 1` значение 0
2. Для последней изменённой записи желательно принудительно установить `val = 1`.

Comment: Задача офигеть недоопределена. Например: выполняем запрос, который вставляет ДВЕ записи - и как определить, какая должна получить единицу? *Попробовал сделать это триггером.* Заведомо порочный подход - апдейтить всю таблицу на каждый чих. *может есть какие-то еще варианты решения помимо триггеров?* Отдельная сервисная таблица, хранящая идентификатор записи для текущей актуальной записи. Либо дополнительное поле у некоей сущности, к которой применяется это "право первой ночи".

Comment: _поле строки с которой оперируют_, что это такое? Например, выбираю строку с id=123, так как оперирирую с этой строкой, то надо установить флаг для этой строки в 1, верно? Добавте всё таки небольшой пример данных и желаемый результат.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос

Comment: То есть, нужно просто найти последнию измененнную запись (вставка новой записи, это тоже изменение). Это так? Интересуют только изменения в текущей сессии, или также изменения в других сессиях?

Comment: Да. Изначально есть запись(и) с val = 1, но нужно чтобы при изменении данных новая запись проставлялась в val = 1, а старая(ые), которые были с val = 1, должны стать val = 0. Аналогично при обновлении записи (она становится текущей - val = 1). Эти изменения происходят в одной сессии.

Comment: А почему вы решили хранить этот флаг в каждой записи таблицы? По сути, вам надо хранить только ид последней измененной записи, т.е. только одно значение, а заводить столбец в таблице для хранения только одного значения, имеет действительно мало смысла.

Comment: Все заточено под такую структуру таблиц (Поле - Флаг). Менять, к сожалению, не могу - затронет много компонентов.

Comment: _Все заточено под такую структуру таблиц_, то есть, ранее допущена ошибка в дизайне таблиц и вы ищете теперь обходной путь, как это исправить. Колонка - флаг хоть может быть NULL, чтобы не хранить 0 во всех записях кроме одной? Какие изменения вы можете делать, например, индекс можете создать?

Comment: Да, и триггер и индекс. Все, кроме структуры таблиц. Null быть не может. Где-то в запросах может быть прописано val = 1

Comment: Запилите view, которая добавит этот флаг из left join с таблицей, в которой хранится id записи с единицей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве обходного пути решения предложу изменить таблицу:

```
create table t0 (id int, memo varchar2 (96), val char (1) not null)
/
alter table t0 drop column val
/
alter table t0 add (lastrow char (1) invisible, val char (1) as (nvl (lastrow, '0')) virtual) 
/
create index idxt0lastrow on t0 (lastrow)
/
```

Сушествующие запросы не заметят это изменение таблицы. Теперь, флаг последнего изменения будет хранится только для одной последней записи. Индекс для быстрого поиска с одной единсвенной записью, т.к. `NULL` значения не индексируются.

В составном триггере для `update` следует указать все столбцы, которые могут быть изменены, а `lastrow` во избежании рекурсивного вызова триггера, там должен быть опущен:

```
create or replace trigger t0lastrowtrig 
for insert or update of id,memo on t0 compound trigger 
    lastchanged rowid;  
    after each row is  
    begin  
        lastchanged := :new.rowid;
    end after each row;
    after statement is  
    begin 
        update t0 set 
            lastrow = case when lastrow is null then 1 end
        where rowid = lastchanged or lastrow=1;
    end after statement;  
end; 
/
```

Тест и результаты:

```
insert into t0 (id, memo) 
    select rownum, 'memo '||rownum from dual connect by level<10;
/
select * from t0
/   
        ID MEMO     VAL
---------- -------- ---
         1 memo 1   0  
[...]
         8 memo 8   0  
         9 memo 9   1  

update t0 set memo = memo||'*'
where id = 5
/
select * from t0
/
        ID MEMO     VAL
---------- -------- ---
         1 memo 1   0  
[...]
         5 memo 5*  1  
[...]
         9 memo 9   0
```

Comment: Не распознает lastrow: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "LASTROW": недопустимый идентификатор

Comment: Повторите в **тестовой** среде все шаги описанные выше. На каком шаге ошибка?

Comment: На этом: alter table t0 add (lastrow char (1) invisible, val char (1) as (nvl (lastrow, '0')) virtual)

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Только что проверил на 12.2 - Table T0 altered. Попробуйте разделить на 2 alter table t0 add ..., т.е. каждую колонку добавить отдельно.

Comment: Да, так прошло. Спасибо. Буду разбираться ))

Comment: Хорошо, на 12.1 уже не могу проверить, снёс.

Comment: Так как такое решение это воркароунд, то использование триггера вполне  приемлимо. Лучше было бы всю логику упаковать в  функции, но надо обеспечить, чтобы приложения обращались только через функции, а не путались вызывать SQL запросы напрямую. Это скорее всего уже невозможно.